# UIScrollView - Disabling isScrollEnabled drags the whole view upwards

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uikit

I have a **UIScrollView** with a couple of subviews, one of them is a **UIStackView** that can be hidden/displayed when a button is pressed.

When the **UIStackView** is hidden I want to disable scrolling on the **UIScrollView** since the content will never have enough height that justifies scrolling being enabled. To achieve that, I'm using:

```
isScrollEnabled.toggle()
```

Problem is, when doing this, the whole view gets dragged up, as if I was scrolling down, causing certain elements to be hidden behind the **navigationBar** and the **statusBar**.
I tried to fix that using the following piece of code:

```
if let navigationBarHeight = vcDelegate?.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.height {
        if let statusBarHeight = window?.windowScene?.statusBarManager?.statusBarFrame.height {
            let totalHeight = navigationBarHeight + statusBarHeight
            setContentOffset(.init(x: 0, y: -totalHeight), animated: true)
        }
    }
```

And that does actually work correctly when the `contentOffset.y` is >= a certain value that I can't precisely specify (because, for some reason, printing the value of `contentOffset.y` only shows a value that is != 0 when I scroll all the way to the bottom of the view.)

When the `contentOffset.y` is < than that mystery value, disabling the scroll will cause the following behavior:

1. The view will be dragged up
2. The view will be dragged down (because I call the `setContentOffset` function)

My bottom line question is: why does the view get dragged up when I disable scrolling? Could it be a constraint issue, some "background" offset change that I should be aware of or something else?

Comment: Will have to look up the implementation about how did you implemented your views. But I guess you don't have to deal with scrollEnabled at all. If you have implemented the scroll view correctly, and the content size of scroll view becomes less than the scroll view itself, the scrolling does not occur by default.

Comment: @pedroeusebio Please try to add a screenshot of your storyboard to show the hierarchy of views so that it is easy for people trying to help you to recreate the issue and help you find a solution. Also this way it stays relevant in the future.

Comment: @AmaisSheikh I suppose I could do it by removing the StackView from the superview but right now I'm showing/hidding the StackView by toggling its isHidden property

Comment: @ShezRatnani I'm doing this programatically, no storyboards :\

Comment: @pedroeusebio can you please add the code here for that then?

Comment: I need to see the exact code in order to solve this, also a bit more info about what is the goal you want to achieve.

Comment: @ShezRatnani sure check this [link](https://github.com/peusebio/hipHopFm/blob/main/hipHopFm/View/AlbumDetailScrollView.swift)

Also, I was able to work this issue around by disabling the animation when setting the content offset after disabling the scroll, but that doesn't feel like the most elegant solution